# CakePHP: Retrieve multiple records from a single model to be edited in one form

Tags: cakephp, model, associations, cakephp-2.0

Good day,

I have a model called ProjectRequirement which belongsTo Project, so Project hasMany ProjectRequirements

When I created the ProjectRequirement entries, I made use of this method:

```
<?php
     echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
          'legend  => false,
          'fieldset' => false,
          'ProjectRequirement.1.description' => ...
          'ProjectRequirement.2.description' => ...
          'ProjectRequirement.3.description' => ...
     ));
?>
```

I did this so that I could make use of the saveMany() method to save multiple records at the same time. However, when I want to edit these records again on the same form, I cannot see, to be able to do it. I have kept the same field naming structure and tried to set the data as follows:

```
<?php
     $this->request->data = $this->ProjectRequirement->find('all', array('conditions' => ...));
?>
```

A pr(); shows that the records are being returned, but they are not populating the form fields. If I remove the numbers and just have a single field like this:

```
<?php
     echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
          'legend  => false,
          'fieldset' => false,
          'ProjectRequirement.description' => ...
     ));
?>
```

It works fine. How can I set the data so that multiple records from ProjectRequirement are set on multiple inout fields? Or can't I?

To reiterate: I do NOT have a problem saving multiple records, I have a problem retrieving multiple records to display.

Regards,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

When you create the form to SAVE many fields, you name the fields like this:

- *ProjectRequirement.1.name...*
- *ProjectRequirement.2.name...*
- *ProjectRequirement.3.name...*
- *...*

However, when retrieving data, it is not the same scenario, and the general rules of arrays and how indexing works are applied here. So simply changing my fields to be like this:

- *ProjectRequirement.0.name...*
- *ProjectRequirement.1.name...*
- *ProjectRequirement.2.name...*
- *...*

Worked because I was only testing with one record in the database, and that row would have been at index 0, not 1.